# My delete a specific line function deletes the content of the entire file

Tags: java

Im still new in java and can't fully understand how BufferedReader and FileWriter really work so some of this were uploaded.This code must delete a line that the user wants to but instead of a line..it deletes the whole file content

```
              Scanner titlerem= new Scanner (System.in);
              System.out.println("Enter student number:");
              title = titlerem.next ();

              System.out.print("Are you sure you want to delete it [Y/N]?");
              String tString = titlerem.next();
              char temp2 = tString.charAt(0);

   switch(temp2)
   {


  case('Y'):
    {

              // construct temporary file
              File inputFile = new File("phonebook.txt");
              File tempFile = new File(inputFile + " ");

              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (new FileReader("phonebook.txt"));
              PrintWriter Pwr = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter (tempFile));
              String line = null;


              while((line = br.readLine()) !=null) {
                  if(line.trim().startsWith(title)){
                      continue; 
                  }
                  else{
                      Pwr.println(line);
                      Pwr.flush();
                  }
              }

            // delete book file before renaming temp
            inputFile.delete();

            // close readers and writers
            Pwr.close();      
            br.close();


           //  rename temp file back to books.txt
            if(tempFile.renameTo(inputFile)){
                 System.out.println("Deletion succesful");
            }
            else
            {
             System.out.println("Update failed");
                  }
     }     



    case('N'):
    {
          System.out.print("Deletion did not proceed");
          break;
    }


       }
```

Can anybody help me.

Comment: File.delete() will delete the entire file, NOT the line it is at. The documentation says as much, and your code comments seem to reflect that intention. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete()

Answer (score 2):

I believe your code is good except that you don't have `break` in your `switch` case statements. So even if the file is properly created and renamed, you will always get the message from the second case statements which may be misleading as it says: Deletion did not proceed

First check on the file system , if contents are edited as it should be even without not having a break statement. If yes, then simply correct your `switch` cases by adding a break statement.

Comment: And first `br.close()` and then `inputFile.delete()`. Also `startsWith(title+" ")` So student 1 will not delete 1, 10, 11, ..., 100, ...